# React-modal setstate not working

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-modal

```
export class StartContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showModal: false
        };

    }

    handleOpenModal = () => {
        console.log("Here")
        //this.setState({ showModal: true }, () =>{ console.log(this.state) });
        this.setState(() => {
            console.log("Changing state")
            return { showModal: true }
          });
    }

    handleCloseModal = () => {
        console.log(this.state.showModal)
        this.setState( );
    }


    render() {
        console.log(this.state)
        return (
            <div>
                <StartComponent handleModalOpen={this.handleOpenModal} />
                <ReactModal
                    isOpen={this.state.showModal}
                    contentLabel="Minimal Modal Example"
                >asda
                    <button onClick={this.handleCloseModal}>Close Modal</button>
                </ReactModal>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

So I am trying to integrate react-modal into my project.

The `this.setState()` method is not called I see no console log, neither when I pass a callback to the setState() methpd.

Can somebody help me please?

Thx for your time!

**UPDATE** -- Start component code.

```
export const StartComponent = (props) => (
<div className="start-page">
    <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-sm-6">
                <NavLink to="/start/klarungsfalle">Einträge prüfen</NavLink>
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-6" >
                <NavLink onClick={props.handleModalOpen} style={{ background: "#aac4d3", cursor: "default" }} to="/">Einträge verfügen</NavLink>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

);

Plus I have to mention that I am also using `redux`.

Comment: What happens when you call `handleModalOpen={() => this.handleOpenModal()}` ?

Comment: `console.log("Here")` is printing something or not? If no then problem might be with your `StartComponent`.

Comment: Can you add the code for StartComponent, my guess is that `handleModalOpen` is not being called from there itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to work for me. I just set up the `<StartComponent />` and it looks like the state is being set how you want.

Try the following snippet which uses your code:

Alternatively you can check out this **[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/VMWpLa)**.

```js
const { HashRouter, NavLink } = ReactRouterDOM;

const App = () => (
  <HashRouter>
    <Modal />
  </HashRouter>
);

const StartComponent = ({currentState, handleModalOpen, handleNix}) => (
  <div className="start-page">
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-sm-6">
          <NavLink to="/start/klarungsfalle" onClick={handleNix}>Einträge prüfen</NavLink>
        </div>
        <div className="col-sm-6">
          <NavLink
            onClick={handleModalOpen}
            style={{ background: "#aac4d3", cursor: "default" }}
            to="/"
            >
            Einträge verfügen
          </NavLink>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className='row justify-center'>
        <div className='col-xs-12'>
          <div>
            <code>Modal</code> state
            <pre>{JSON.stringify(currentState)}</pre>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);


class Modal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showModal: false
    };
  }

  handleOpenModal = () => {
    console.log("Here");
    this.setState(() => {
      console.log(`Changing state to 'showModal: ${this.state.showModal}'`);
      return { showModal: true };
    });
  };
  
  handleNix = () => {
    alert("hier gibt's nichts");
  }

  handleCloseModal = () => {
    console.log(this.state.showModal);
    this.setState(() => {
      console.log(`Changing state to 'showModal: ${this.state.showModal}'`);
      return { showModal: false };
    });
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <StartComponent
          handleModalOpen={this.handleOpenModal}
          handleNix={this.handleNix}
          currentState={this.state}/>
        <ReactModal
          isOpen={this.state.showModal}
          contentLabel="Minimal Modal Example">
          <div className="flex columns-center">
            <div className="note">
              The modal hides the Stack Overflow console. Look behind the modal
              or open your JS console.
            </div>
            <div className="flex">
              <div>
                <code>Modal</code> state
                <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state)}</pre>
              </div>
              <button
                className="btn btn-sm btn-danger"
                onClick={this.handleCloseModal}>
                Close Modal
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ReactModal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.justify-center {
  justify-content: center;
}

.space-around {
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.columns-center {
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.note {
  font-size: 0.7em;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.btn:after {
  content: "\01F436";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="app"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom/umd/react-router-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-modal/2.3.2/react-modal.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @user2960896 The above example uses your updated code as well. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be some missing bindings needed for es6 when working with events. So for handlers to access state just put these bindings in you constructor :

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        showModal: false
    };
    // bindings
    this.handleOpenModal = this.handleOpenModal.bind(this);
    this.handleCloseModal = this.handleCloseModal.bind(this);
}
```

Anonymous functions are not needed there :

```
 handleOpenModal() {
    this.setState({showModal: true});
}

handleCloseModal() {
    this.setState({showModal: false});
}
```

Comment: Object and function both can be passed to `setState`.

Answer (score 0):

Passing a callback into setState means that when setState finishes it'll run that function next; setState is async, but that's not going to help you here. It might be helpful to provide the code for your StartComponent component as it's likely your handler function isn't being called.

try `onClick={() => props.handleModalOpen()}`

Note: just a suggestion, consider naming your props the same thing in child as in parent cause handleModalOpen and handleOpenModal can get confusing.

Comment: try `onClick={() => props.handleModalOpen()}`

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind functions to use 'this' keyword

```
 constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        showModal: false
    };
    this.handleOpenModal = this.handleOpenModal.bind(this);
    this.handleCloseModal = this.handleCloseModal.bind(this);
}
```